# How to remove ubuntu from up's government laptop

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, disk-management

I have got HP Pavilion g4 notebook from UP Government and i want to remove Ubuntu from it and only have windows 7 in it and i want to make disk partition (Local disk C,D,E and F).
So please
help me.

Comment: Is Win7 already installed on the notebook?

Comment: yes it has two operating system win 7 and ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

First, select windows from the boot manager, and after starting the boot, press F8 to get the Advanced startup screen (white text on black)

Then choose "Repair your Computer"

Next, adjust the language/keyboard settings.

If Prompted, enter an administrator's username/password to gain access to the recover enviroment.

Select the "Command Prompt"

Enter "bootrec /fixmbr" and press enter'

Close the command prompt

reboot the system.

You may now use disk management to delete the partitions that were created to install linux.

First, right click on "Computer" in the start menu, and select "manage"

If prompted, allow the UAC dialog.

Choose Disk Management from the left sidebar (it's under storage)

You will see a list of all partitions on the system, for each of the linux partitions, right click them, and choose "Delete volume"

Now you can use the Extend Volume option to reclaim the disk space that was used by linux into your main parition.

Good Luck

Comment: Great explanation! Voted up!

Comment: Cant we just boot the system to windows then open the built-in disk management utility and delete the partions containing ubuntu files?

Comment: @Swarup Somanna The first half makes sure the standard windows MBR is installed instead of the GRUB MBR that was likely installed when Ubuntu was. If this step is omitted, the system may try to boot GRUB without the linux /boot partition being available, resulting in a very unfriendly rescue prompt from GRUB.

Comment: @KJ4IPS ok now I get it. Thank you for the explanation